# Training discriminator and generator at the same time(Tensorflow)

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network, generative-adversarial-network

Usually in GAN codes using TensorFlow, we have the following form:

```
 _, D_loss_curr, _ = sess.run(
            [D_solver, D_loss, clip_D],
            feed_dict={X: X_mb, z: sample_z(mb_size, z_dim)}
        )

 _, G_loss_curr = sess.run(
        [G_solver, G_loss],
        feed_dict={z: sample_z(mb_size, z_dim)}
    )
```

Which can be seen as training discriminator(D) first and then training generator(G). However, what if we do the following:

```
 _, D_loss_curr, _ ,_, G_loss_curr= sess.run(
                [D_solver, D_loss, clip_D,G_solver, G_loss],
                feed_dict={X: X_mb, z: sample_z(mb_size, z_dim)}
            )
```

Does it now mean and D and G are being trained in parallel? Or compared to before, G is now getting "outdated" D?

Answer (score 0):

The discriminator D and the generator G will not be trained in parallel when passing the list `[D_solver, D_loss, clip_D, G_solver, G_loss]` to function `sess.run()`. All operations of this list will be executed, but the function `Session.run()` cannot guarantee any order of execution of those operations. It may happen that G is executed before D or vice-versa.

This behavior of [Session.run()](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Session#run) was discussed in previous issues of tensorflow: [#13133](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/13133) and [#10860](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/10860).

**Edit:** adding answer for rephrased question

If you call `sess.run` twice, as in your example, you will train the discriminator D first, and then the generator G.
If you call `sess.run` just once, with all operations for D and G in the list `fetches`, all operations in that list will be executed in some order. But there is no guarantee of which order it will be. At each call, D can be trained first, then G, or G can be trained first, then D. 
The function `Session.run()` follows an order of execution and does not run the operations in parallel, i.e., the graph operations are not executed at the same time. This order of execution is not necessarily the order that you passed in `fetches=[D_solver, D_loss, clip_D, G_solver, G_loss]`.

For example, consider the second scenario, where we pass all operations in just one call of `sess.run()`. At your first iteration of training it may happen that `G_loss` is executed first, after that `G_solver` is executed, then `D_solver`, etc. At the second iteration, we may actually get that `D_loss` is executed first, then `D_solver`, then `G_solver`, etc.

Example with order of execution performed by `sess.run` at each iteration (without `clip_D`):
Iteration 1: G_loss, G_solver, D_solver, D_loss
Iteration 2: D_loss, D_solver, G_solver, G_loss
Iteration 3: G_solver, G_loss, D_loss, D_solver
Iteration 4: G_solver, G_loss, D_loss, D_solver ...

With this approach, you will not have a pattern in your training. For example, at the first iteration we train G before training D. At the second iteration, we train D without any recent update in G, i.e., G was not trained between the training of D in iteration 1 and 2.

On the other hand, when considering the first scenario where we sequentially train D and G, we guarantee that at each iteration of our training, D is trained before G, and the metrics for D are calculated before the training of G, and the metrics for G are calculated after the training of D.

Comment: better phrased question perhaps: If I call sess.run twice, once with update to D(D_solver, D_loss) and once with update to G(G_solver, G_loss), how is this different from calling sess.run once with D and G in same condition (D_solver, D_loss, G_solver, G_loss). My understanding is that calling sess.run twice will result in a sequential execution of D and G and calling it only once with all params will result in simultaneous execution of D and G(i.e. D's weights will get update at the same time as G's, whereas in sequential D's weights will be updated first and G's later).

Comment: I edited the answer for the rephrased question. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you @K. Bogdan. I am still a bit confused, here is what I am trying to do. I want to calculate loss of D and G and then backpropogate the gradients of both at the same time. That is, I don't want G to use updated D when calculating it's loss. I can easily do it in pytorch by putting D_loss.backward(), D_solver.step(), G_loss.backward(), G_solver.step() sequentially after calculating loss of D and G. That is why I thought I can do it in TF like I mentioned. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think you can check [Distributed Tensorflow](https://www.tensorflow.org/deploy/distributed) for this. But, why do you need to backpropagate the gradients of both G and D at the same time?

Comment: @k-bogdan It has to do with a project I'm working on, essentially to make sure that D and G are trained in a way that makes sure G's gradients are not based on updated D, or in other words that D does not get updated gradients before calculating G's loss. Just wondering, will grouping the loss functions with tf.group() work?